# Distinguish additionaly added marker (waypoint) on leaflet-routing-machine

Tags: leaflet

I have Leaflet map with leaflet-routing-machine. I set few waypoints and all work fine.

But now I want alter the way. I drag it, map set additional waypoint and now route goes through this extra point.

How can I understand that this waypoint is 'extra' one (not includes in predefined set of points) in `instructions` properties of route . Maybe I can set special label for it?

I have lat, lng for my predefined points, but I want have distance between all MY points.